# Passing color as argument when using StdDraw in java

Tags: java, colors, stddraw

Having some trouble passing color argument if at all possible when using StdDraw in Java.

What I would like to do is passing a color variable f.e. "RED", "GREEN", "BLUE" to set the pen color of the drawing function to get different color each time I run through for loop.

Here is the code for more details of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
static void DrawCircleSizeColor()
    {
    String[] myColorArray = {"RED","GREEN","BLUE"};
    double x = 20;
    double y = 20;
    double r = 20;
    int c = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3.0; i++)
    {

        StdDraw.setPenColor(Color.getColor(myColorArray[c]));
        StdDraw.circle(x, y, r);
        c++;
        r--;
    }
```

Hope you understand my where I am going with this

Thanks 
-EE

Comment: Anything helpful in the [tag:stddraw] tag?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.awt.Color;
```

declare your array as:

```
Color[] myColorArray = {Color.RED,Color.GREEN,Color.BLUE};
```

and use them

```
StdDraw.setPenColor(myColorArray[c));
```

Class [java.awt.Color](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) has static variables with some standard colors predefined